# Watchdog - monitor directory for a creation of new files but ignore if file with a same filename already existed

Tags: python, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am trying to run my program for every new file in a folder. Trying to implement monitoring with a Watchdog, I stumbled upon the following problem.
What does my program do to every new file in a folder?
It changes it(some parameters in it)in a means that it creates a new file with the same filename. I want a watchdog to detect when I have a new file in a directory, then to run my program, create a new file with the same filename(that's what my program does), but, most important, I don't want it to run my program again on the same file.
Is it possible to do?

Here is the MWE that I already have tried.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.events import FileCreatedEvent
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler  

class MyMonitorFolder(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.fits"]
    
    def process(self, event):
        src_path = "A/B/"
        myProgram(src_path)
        
    def on_created(self, event):
        print (str(datetime.now()) + " " + str(event))
        self.process(event)
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyMonitorFolder()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=src_path, recursive=False)
    print("Monitoring started")
    observer.start()
    
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding other `on_x` methods to your `MyMonitorFolder` class?

```
class MyMonitorFolder(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.fits"]
    
    def process(self, event):
        src_path = "A/B/"
        myProgram(src_path)
        
    def on_created(self, event):
        print (str(datetime.now()) + " " + str(event))
        self.process(event)

    def on_modified(self, event):
        pass

    def on_moved(self, event):
        pass

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        pass
```

I'm using watchdog on windows and these seem to be working. What is your os?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I just did, but it still does the same, probably because my program still generates new file with the same filename, and watchdog detects it as a new file. I am running it on linux.